# yiiframe how to count the seats

Tags: php, yii

I have created a table named `screen`. I have `booked seats` and `seats` as columns. I want to increment `booked seats` one by one and when `booked seats` and `seats` are equal I want to echo `"tickets fulled"`.

```
 public function actionfulltickets($id)
 {
  $screen1=screen::model()->findByPk($id);
  $booked+=screen1.booked_seats;
  if(screen1.seats==screen1.booked_seats)
  {
  $info="tickets fulled";
  echo cjson::encode($info);
 }
```

Comment: plz say me the code i didnt get the output for this function..

Comment: What exactliy should we do for you?

Comment: Please edit your post and ask something.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionfulltickets($id)
{
    $screen1=screen::model()->findByPk($id);
    // check have avaiable ticket or not.
    if(screen1->seats==screen1->booked_seats)
    {
       $info="tickets fulled";
       echo cjson::encode($info);
    } else {
       screen1->booked_seats++;
       screen1->save();
       $info="booked successful";
       echo cjson::encode($info);
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Can you capture screen or message error and post to here?

Comment: It shows like Unexpected symbol .Plz slove this problem

Comment: no i have table named booked seats starts from the count of zero..then how - will come

Comment: you said you have table screen with cloumn booked_seats and seats right?

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);